# can not see table in tree view of sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I can not see table in tree view of sql developer

but I can execute select statement for that table.

I logged in with 'carspgm' user and I executed below query then i can see the data but when I expand the carsdb table tree I can not see this below table.

I want to find out why I can not see and I want to find what all trigger are there on this table

```
select * from carsdb.COMAPNY_STATE
```

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the "Other USers" treenode, and you should see "CARSDB" schema under which you will see objects owned by that user/schema.

Comment: i can see lot of other table except this table(COMPANY_STATE)

Comment: Has carspgm been granted select to "carsdb.COMAPNY_STATE" (or should it be COMPANY_STATE - check your original post) via a role or directly. WHat you see when you do :

SELECT * from all_tab_privs where table_name in ( 'COMPANY_STATE', 'COMAPNY_STATE' ).

Answer (score 0):

check with the following

```
select * from user_tables where table_name='COMAPNY_STATE';
--the above query will return the data of table

desc COMAPNY_STATE;
--the above statement will describes the tables with columns and their data typed
```

If the first statement was executed then return a row then table was created.
If  second statement was executed and table was exist.